# Python проверить чтобы строка содержала только русские и латинские буквы

Tags: python, строки

Как проверить чтобы строка содержала только русские и латинские буквы верхнего и нижнего регистра?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated** (@Sour Sourse) 
Вероятно, так:

```
re.search(r'[^a-zA-Z а-яА-ЯёЁ]',a )
```

Например:

```
import re

a = "testтест"

if re.search(r'[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]',a ):
     print("error")
else:
     print("ok")

a = "test4тест"

if re.search(r'[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]',a ):
    print("error")
else:
    print("ok")
```

Comment: Пропустит `ёЁ`.

Comment: @SourSourse справедливо

Answer (score 1):

```
"HelloПриветЁё".isalpha()
True

"Hello ПриветЁё".isalpha()
False
```

Comment: `>>>'ẞ'.isalpha()  # True` но `ẞ` явно не кириллический\латинский символ.

Comment: @Sour Sourse Просветите пожалуйста что такое символ `ẞ` и где он находится на вашей клавиатуре?

Comment: это немецкая буква. зачем мне вам говорить что у меня есть на клавиатуре? в вопросе ни слова не сказано о способе ввода.